# Display Images from internet in a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am making an application which gets urls of images through my web services.I want to diplay that images in the application backgound.How can i do it? Is it required to download all images before displaying? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display images via an `Image` control, which you can position wherever you like. In order to display an image from a URL, you can do the following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/80000/5000/100/85108/85108.strip.print.gif", UriKind.Absolute)
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

As per this question:

[Silverlight Windows Phone 7: Load Images From URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455195/silverlight-windows-phone-7-load-images-from-url)

Comment: this will download the image everytime, you should ideally save it to isolated storage, check for the image next time, if its not there, then only go for the web image. Else it will drain the bandwidth. Correct me if I am wrong?